# angular js validation not working using its own directives

Tags: angularjs

i am using angular js directives but it's not working can any on know what i am doing wrong i follow angular js documentation but not working is there any library required is something wrong in my form .

loginView.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="user_form" novalidate ng-submit='login()'>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>Login</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="login-Name" class="col-lg-3 form-label">User Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="login-Name" ng-model="user.username" name="login-Name" placeholder="User Name" required/>
                            <div class="error" ng-show="user_form.login-Name.$dirty && user_form.login-Name.$invalid">
                                <small class="error" ng-show="user_form.login-Name.$error.required">
                                    User name is required.
                                </small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="login-Password" class="col-lg-3 form-label">Password:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login-Password" ng-model="user.password" name="login-Password" placeholder="Password" ng-minlength=6 ng-maxlength=20 required/>
                            <div class="error" ng-show="user_form.login-Password.$dirty && user_form.login-Password.$invalid">
                                <small class="error" ng-show="user_form.login-Password.$error.required">
                                    Your Password is required.
                                </small>
                                <small class="error" ng-show="user_form.login-Password.$error.minlength">
                                    Your Password is required to be at least 6 characters
                                </small>
                                <small class="error" ng-show="user_form.login-Password.$error.maxlength">
                                    Your Password cannot be longer than 20 characters
                                </small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Login
                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Comment: `not working` is just not enough of a problem description....create a demo in plunker or jsfiddle.net that replicates issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in your code.

First one, you used - in your fields id (login-Name and login-Password). Replace them by _ (login_Name and login_Password). Angularjs see them as the substract operator and doesn't return an object to evaluate in the ng-show directives.

For the username (the email address), your error will never be displayed since the $error.required is set to false as soon as the field is not empty and $dirty is set to false if the field is empty. Your 2 conditions cannot be true at the same time.

For the password, you have the same problem for the required field, but your 2 other validations will work if you change your id.

Working example : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4CezkHFW71trtu1DcLS8)